# ElasticSearch transform array of string into terms

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a index that contains list of url as array

Schema:

```
{
    "locations": {
        "type": "keyword"
    }
}
```

example document

```
{
    "locations": [
        "https://google.com",
        "https://yahoo.com"
    ]
}
```

I want to use a transform to create a new index, which contains list of urls with number of occurrence.

I tried creating transform like this:

```
{
    "pivot": {
        "group_by": {
            "user_id": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "userId"
                }
            }
        },
        "aggs": {
            "locations": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "locations.raw",
                    "order": {
                        "_count": "desc"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // source and dest definition here 
}
```

Transform was successfully created without error but resulting document always has `locations` as empty array. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any `locations.raw` field in your mapping, hence why the array is empty.

So, in your transform you simply need to refer to `locations` instead

```
{
    "pivot": {
        "group_by": {
            "user_id": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "userId"
                }
            }
        },
        "aggs": {
            "locations": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "locations",            <--- change this
                    "order": {
                        "_count": "desc"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // source and dest definition here 
}
```